# What defines an extra?

Tags: credits

Me and my family are currently having a debate about what constitutes an extra in a movie.

We have opposing theories about *what* makes a person's role in a film as an extra or as a proper character.

I will lay out my argument and my parents' argument. Please answer with which (if any) you agree with.

## My argument

I believe that an extra is someone who appears on camera and may be given one or two lines to say. They only appear in one scene and don't draw a great deal of attention to themselves. An example would be [Lee Child in *Jack Reacher*](https://youtu.be/HSGaycBZpCc): a police officer who gives Jack Reacher his things back after being in jail.

## My parents argument

Anyone who isn't named. Either their character doesn't have a name or they are not credited for their role. They may say any amount of lines but they cannot be named. One example would be the [world's most famous extra](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jesse_Heiman) in *Transformers : Dark of the Moon*.

## Your arguments

Please post which idea you agree with. If it's neither, feel free to post your own definition of an extra.

*I can't think of an appropriate tag. Please feel free to edit with your ideas for one*

Comment: This seems to be primarily opinion-based.  However, to counter your parents' argument about "any character without a name" you may want to reference the classic Clint Eastwood [Dollars Trilogy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dollars_Trilogy) - the **main character** in which is known simply as "the Man with No Name"

Comment: If they have lines, they're not an extra. I recall reading once that if you speak a maximum of five words, you're something like a "glorified extra" (hence waiters etc in movies being very curt), and that anything more gets you a credit.

Comment: @Steve-O - from an audience perspective, there will always be some element of guesswork. From a production perspective, the distinction is very clear. It is not 'line-dependant' in quite so cut & dried way, so that's not going to help the audience make the distinction. Ref also 'our man' in All is Lost, for a principal [I mean absolute mega-star!!] with no name, nor really much in the way of lines ;-)

Comment: By their logic Edward Norton is just an extra in Fight Club, as is Clint Eastwood in a few of his spaghetti westerns. - oops, CE was already mentioned.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Let me try to define it the way I see it, from a UK perspective, which seems slightly different from the US.

It's very easy to tell, if you are in a production, who is a principal and who an extra - or as we prefer to call them over here, Supporting Artists*, SAs for short.

- A principal has a driver and car to bring them to set; an SA gets the bus.
- A principal has a trailer known as a three-way because it's divided into 3 separate accommodations - only Tom Cruise gets one all to himself**; an SA gets to share a double-decker bus or some old school/church hall [cheerfully known as 'crowd base'] and communal changing facilities.
- A Principal eats with the crew; an SA stands away from the lunch queue until everyone else has got theirs.
  Note: only for Hollywood movies are the principals treated like untouchables, being fetched and carried in all aspects. For the most, they 'muck in' with the crew and don't consider themselves demigods.
- A principal is always credited, even if their character name is 'man in pub' and all they said was one line; an SA is never credited, even if they got a line. [This has some grey area - some SAs are also actors, so might in certain circumstances get a quick promotion, at the 2nd assistant director's discretion, but it is not common.]
- A principal - though not officially entitled to this perk, as it is *technically* only for crew, gets [Craft](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Craft_service) - good coffee, snacks, smoothies, all the treats. An SA gets a tea-table - hot water, instant coffee sachets and tea bags, DIY.

---

## Examples

To differentiate using examples from one show I know and work on, which I know also is broadcast in many countries, [*Call the Midwife*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1983079/?ref_=nv_sr_1)

A **Day Player** is not an extra but a principal, an actor booked for a small role, which is potentially [but not always] shot in a day. Sometimes a day player can go on to become a regular character, e.g. Daniel Laurie who played Reggie in the last series, initially as a day player, but 'promoted' to the regular cast for season 7.
The day players you will see in every episode are those playing this week's 'mum & dad' - the expectant couple each episode centres on and whose story is completed in that one episode. As the shoot is 9 episodes over 6 months, that means those day players will be on set for perhaps one or two weeks.
They are **Principals**, named characters, and check out on all the bullet points above.

An **extra**, on the other hand, can be seen walking past in the background every time people are needed to make the place look busy.
They generally don't speak at all, unless some general 'hubbub' is required; they instead pretend to be having conversations, shrug shoulders, wave hands and in all tend to look slightly over-animated compared to 'real people' [in-joke]
If they are distant from the camera, this over-acting works well, if close it can look awkward.

An **SA** may be called upon to do a single line, specific or generic, for which they will get extra money - known as a 'feature'.
A feature is a double-edged sword. Yes, it gets you in front of the camera for your own close-up if you're lucky, but it can also lock you out of the rest of the series if production think your character would be too recognisable in other scenes.

---

## Combined example

Back to *Call the Midwife*... When the scene is in front of Nonatus House [where the nuns & midwives live] or in the Community Centre etc they are "in Poplar", the area of London the show is centred around.
When they are "in Poplar", all the passers-by [SAs] are 'locals' - the characters they portray all live in the area. They can therefore be the same people each time, racking up 20 or 30 days' work across the series.
If you watch carefully you will see the same people, in different outfits, walking in different couples with different kids, in pretty much every crowd scene across the whole 9 episodes. (Hence the dilemma if you get a feature - you want to swap 30 days' work for one day plus 20 quid? ;-) They do swap and change the SAs, but from a core of about 50 regulars.
When they are "not in Poplar" those same regulars cannot be seen, so a fresh batch of SAs are brought in for that.

---

## EastEnders

To use another example, to show how far you can go and still be categorised as an 'extra' rather than a principal...
*EastEnders*. The market traders are all 'extras'. They each have their own market stall and are in pretty much every single episode - but instead of being paid by the day with extra money for being featured, they are instead contracted. They are guaranteed a given income in exchange for a set number of days' work per year. They may be called on to say lines or interact with principals at any time, without receiving specific compensation for that.

---

## Summary

It's difficult to tell from an audience perspective. The main clue would be if they are credited - and for this let's choose to ignore edge cases like Stan Lee in the Marvel universe, also that a cameo is in itself an edge case. A famous actor doing a single line is still a famous actor and will have been given all considerations and courtesies appropriate to their status rather than role.

As mentioned elsewhere - a principal went through the audition process [though not always] whereas an SA was picked from a sheet of photos [again not always].
A principal was booked by an acting agent, an SA by an SA agency.

These are all things the audience cannot see in their attempts to differentiate.

One additional thing to note.
You cannot rely on IMDB to differentiate a principal from an extra. Many seasoned extras credit their own performances in shows, giving themselves 'popularity' and pushing themselves further up the rankings.
Their self-accreditation does not make them a principal. Only the show's official credits as rolled at the end of that show can be considered any authority on the matter.

---

*Yes, I'm fully aware that's like calling a spade a manual earth-moving implement, but that's their official title. The word 'extra' is frowned on in the industry [officially.]

** and Jeremy Piven [Harry Selfridge], but that's because he brought his own, from the US ;)

Comment: Beyond a few notable exceptions (e.g. a CGI Tommy Lee Jones as Agent K), most extras can be easily replaced an/or multiplied by modern CGI and often are (e.g. elven troops in LOTR, stormtroopers in Star Wars, etc).

Comment: @Jeeped - 'Most extras can easily be replaced'… I think that's so far out from the norm as to be notable when it happens, not notable when it doesn't. You're only considering the very highest budget productions, not the thousands of others who simply have neither the budget nor the 200 CGI artists to do it. Then there are artistic considerations; Dumbo, for instance, CGI elephant, real people right the way through. Up to 650 a day in those big tops, for weeks on end, rather than CGI them.

Answer (score 13):

Each countries actors association(s) will have their own definition but in general, I understand, these are pretty similar...*and well defined*.

Extras (also, I think, more commonly referred to sometimes as "background performers") **are** generally silent and will earn a higher pay rate if required to speak or perform a more noticeable action.

[**Screen Actors Guild**](http://www.sagaftra.org/extra-performers)

> How does a background performer qualify for an upgrade to **principal performer**?
>
> There are several ways to qualify for an upgrade to principal performer. Here are the most common:
>
> - A performer is directed to speak a line (other than omnies*); or
> - A performer is performing an identifiable stunt; or
> - A performer is in the (1) foreground, (2) identifiable, and (3) demonstrating or illustrating a product or service or illustrating or reacting to the on/off camera narration or commercial message. The performer must meet all 3 criteria simultaneously to qualify for a principal upgrade.
>
> <sup>An “omni” is defined as atmospheric words or sounds, such as cheering at a sports event, spoken by a group.</sup>

So...it has nothing to do with an on screen **NAME**. It comes down to, logically, to how much and what kind of work the actor is required to perform.

Comment: @Paulie_D Excellent answer.  I suspect this usage of the term derives from the Hollywood system, thus it's salient you use SAG as your example.

Answer (score 2):

As a former actor, I define it by the casting call. If you are required to audition which sometimes includes lines but not always then you are a casted day player. If the casting call is asking for extras, or background players and only requires a sent in photo and resume then you are an extra.

Comment: Does this mean that 'extras' are the same as 'background players'?